# Has anybody yet backported Lambda Expressions to Java 7?

Tags: java, lambda, java-7, java-8, backport

Reading about [what kind of bytecode Java 8 produces from lambdas](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2013/04/i-can-haz-lambda-on-java-7.html), it came to my mind the time when Java 5 was released. Back then there was [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) and [other tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_backporting_tools) for converting bytecode compiled with JDK 5 to run on JRE 1.4.

**Has anybody yet created such a backporting tool for Java 8 lambdas?** It would let Java developers start using lambdas already today on production-quality Java 7 JREs, without having to wait 6-12 months for Java 8's GA release.

Here is my analysis of why such as backporter should be implementable relatively easily:

Java 8 lambdas don't seem to use any JVM features that Java 7 wouldn't have (e.g. `invokedynamic`), and the `java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory` class and its dependencies look like pure Java, so it should be possible to implement them in a 3rd-party library. Thus bytecode compiled with JDK 8 could be made to run on JRE 7 by adding a 3rd-party library with a copy of LambdaMetafactory (under a different package) and by transforming the bytecode to use that metafactory instead. Maybe also generate some synthetic classes and methods to bypass accessibility checks, as `java.lang.invoke.MagicLambdaImpl` seems to imply. Or then generate anonymous inner classes for all lambdas, like some of the first lambda-enabled Early Access JDKs did.

Comment: In case nobody reports such a thing soon, I might write one. Here is the (currently empty) github repository: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: Hmmm... this would meet a real demand. If you can get it to work correctly and with as few limitations as possible, I think it's a winner.

Comment: I experimented a bit on my own and found out that with bytecode transformation it is even possible to run the classes compiled for Java 8 directly with a Java 7 JVM with an appropriate javaagent. The JVM will accept the classes even when they have an unsupported format as long as the instrumentation via registered class file tranformers results in a known, valid format. I did not implement all features (yet) but I think it’s a promising approach as keeping the deployed classes unmodified means they might still benefit from future Java 8 versions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is now [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) for converting Java 8 bytecode, which uses lambda expressions and method references, to work on Java 7, 6 or 5. (Java 1.4 gave verify errors; did not investigate further.)

Comment: AFAIK, nobody has yet tried it on Dalvik, though the wish has been mentioned a couple of times. Do you want to be the first one to test it and write a blog post? ;)

Comment: I hear it works on Dalvik. See [this comment](http://blog.orfjackal.net/2013/07/lambda-expressions-backported-to-java-7.html?showComment=1374655919855#c222763220984063335).

Comment: Very, very, very dangerous! This compiles code against the Java 8 APIs, which may be different or not exist on Java 7. You'll never know until runtime. I strongly recommend you avoid this! A slightly different (but safe) approach would be to use xtend, which compiles to Java 7 source.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield That's why all tests (from unit to end-to-end tests) need to be run under Java 7 or whatever is the target platform, as said in Retrolambda's documentation: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda#tips Here's how to do it - just a single line of configuration: https://github.com/orfjackal/jumi/blob/18208dc8b0b10f524eb232059526b523bbcee406/parent/pom.xml#L286

Comment: The key being "all tests" - you absolutely must have _all_ Java runtime calls covered by unit tests to double check. That amount of coverage is only feasible in the most trivial applications. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: You should *anyways* fully test your programs. Your point is moot.

Comment: Also, it would be straightforward to write a program that goes through all instructions in a program to check that the APIs they use exist, if you are not properly testing your programs.

Comment: @rekire another person has made a Gradle plugin for it: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda