# mutiple java version for running application

Tags: java, versions

In my current environment ,

1) I have hadoop running with `java version "1.7.0_91"`

2) I have a new requirement where I have to install `neo4j 3.0` which require `java 8` which I have installed but not used as default. The default version used is `"1.7.0_91"` only.

Now my question is how can I point my `neo4j` to run `1.8` while without disturbing the old version. Both the java version are installed under /usr/java

I tried this command to run

```
neo4j install 
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:$PATH ./bin/neo4j start
```

but no luck, can someone please help me resolve this issue

Comment: You can change your current java version http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-default-java-version-linux.html

Comment: Did you try to set JAVA_HOME as well?

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 and 8 are compatible with each other, why would you run two versions? Just run everything under Java 8.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As I have different version, before starting the neo4j, I am using an export command as export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60 and then I am starting neo4j, the other way around is we can add the export command in the script which I am calling in start neo4j. This solved.

Answer (score 0):

Java is Backwards Compatible. It means that you can run Java 7 programs on Java 8 platform.

See this [oracle documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upgrading_major_java_versions).

> **Backward Compatibility**
>
> Java versions are expected to be binary backwards-compatible. For
>   example, JDK 8 can run code compiled by JDK 7 or JDK 6. It is common
>   to see applications leverage this backwards compatibility by using
>   components built by different Java version. A Compatibility Guide
>   (explained later) exists for each major release to provide special
>   mention when something is not backwards compatible.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610424/2815219) stackoverflow answer for more insights.