# How to list all incompatible dependancy version with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm in to process of upgrading from 1.6 to 1.8.

Because of this, I'm looking for a good way to list all dependencies that aren't Java 1.8 compatible. I've got JAVA_HOME is already set. and I'm using Maven 3.3.9.

#### I'm looking for something like:

```
mvn dependancy:compatabilityTest
```

#### Environment Info:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Data\apps\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there are libraries running fine under Java 6 but not under Java 8? Thanks to JRE backwards compatibility, I suspect not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610400/a-program-made-with-java-8-can-be-run-on-java-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible

Comment: Yeah, getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name some.path.SomeClassTest. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15

Comment: There is no good reason a class is incompatible, it's not a standard thing but a rare bug. You really have to go out of your way to find such a case.

Comment: I'm seeing it in Mockitto, or in a class that mockito is messing w/ as far as I can tell. Maybe it's a bug in mockito

Answer (score 1):

"Failed to transform class with name" most likely means byte code generation or transformation is being used. There is no way to determine this statically as the class doesn't exist in the form it will be loaded until the program is run.

Java 8 adds some validation to the byte code which wasn't in older versions. This means byte code generated in Java 5.0 which wasn't valid might not have failed but now it does. The solution is to upgrade the version of the byte code generator and most likely the library which uses it.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it might be related to the javassist version being used.

Comment: It was an issue w/ the default javassist jar. I manually set it to a different version and all my tests were fixed.