# does javac -target option make jdk backward compatible?

Tags: java, javac

since javac support -target option, does it mean that I can use any new feature of a latest jdk, and make it work on an older JRE version?

For example if I use jdk 8's new featres and use -target 1.5, will the program work fine in JRE 1.5?

Comment: Of course it won't.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610400/a-program-made-with-java-8-can-be-run-on-java-7

Comment: Java 5 code should, in theory, be runnable on a Java 8 JRE, but not vice-versa.  _Backwards_ compatibility is supported, but not necessarily _forwards_.